# Handling non-blocking nature of Node while Database querying

Tags: mysql, node.js, nonblocking

I created a function which takes an array of employees. I need to find out the education details of each employee which are on a different table in mysql and attach that to the particular Employee object.

Here's how the employee object looks like:

```
 employee: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
 }
```

Here's the function that I wrote:

```
const getEducationDetails = (employees, done) => {
        var empArr = [];

        employees.forEach(employee => {
            empArr.push(employee);
            employee.education = [];

            const sql = `SELECT * FROM employee_education_details 
                        WHERE employee_id = "${employee.id}"`

                db.query(sql, (err, educationDetails, fields) => {

                employee.education.push(educationDetails);

            });        

        });

    return done(empArr);
}
```

So, I created a custom empArr array and pushed each employee object into that. To store the education details, I created employee['education']. The problem arises because of the non-blocking I/O technique of nodejs.

Node is not waiting for the mysql query to finish and hence returning empArr even before inserting the education details inside it.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to solve this problem here.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but the asynchronous nature of your select query means that you _shoudn't_ be attempting to use the results from that until it has finished.  When has it finished?  When the anonymous callback function gets called.  That is where you should be making use of the results, not before that.

Comment: you can `return done(empArr)` in the callback of your `db` query.

Comment: @vibhor1997a The query is inside a forEach loop. I can't return inside that

Comment: @marukobotto Oh sorry :(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you show an example? I'm not really getting this.

Comment: What I'm saying is your logic is off.  You shouldn't be returning from this function with the results of the the query.  Rather, the async callback should be the one to do something with those results.  Change your thinking.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand. But the async function is inside a loop. Then I have to run the query inside a for loop and check the length of the array with the value of i. When it matches then return it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `Promises`. You can do this using `promises` like below :

```
const getEducationDetails = (employees, done) => {
    var empPromArr = [];
    employees.forEach(employee => {
        let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            empArr.push(employee);
            employee.education = [];
            let empEduPromises = [];
            empEduPromises.push(query(employee));
            Promise.all(empEduPromises).then(educationDetails => {
                employee.education = educationDetails;
                resolve(employee)
            }, err => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
        empPromArr.push(p);
    });
    Promise.all(empPromArr).then(empArr => {
        return done(empArr);
    }, err => {
        //error handling
    });
}

function query(employee) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sql = `SELECT * FROM employee_education_details 
    WHERE employee_id = "${employee.id}"`
        db.query(sql, (err, educationDetails, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(educationDetails);
            }
        });
    });
}
```